# PyTorch Lightning complex-valued CNN training outputs NaN after 1 batch

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, nan, pytorch-lightning

I have built a complex-valued CNN using [ComplexPyTorch](https://github.com/wavefrontshaping/complexPyTorch), where the layers are wrapped in a `torch.ModuleList`. When running the network I get through the validation sanity check and 1 batch of the training, then my loss outputs NaNs. Logging gradients in `on_after_backward` shows NaNs immediately. Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can troubleshoot this?

I have a real-valued version of the network where I'm not using [ComplexPyTorch](https://github.com/wavefrontshaping/complexPyTorch) and everything works fine so I can't help but feeling that during the network's backward pass there is a problem with my layers being in a `torch.ModuleList`. Also, I hard-coded the network without a `torch.ModuleList` and didn't get this issue either.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested, I set `detect_anomaly=True` in `Trainer`, then was able to trace the torch function outputting NaNs during backpropagation. In my case it was `torch.atan2` so I added a tiny epsilon to its denominator and fixed it, but as a general point I've always found denominator epsilons to be really helpful in preventing NaNs from dividing functions!